# Calculating slope of non-null points for a row of observations in Python

Tags: python, numpy

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'price':[4.95, 5.04, 4.88, 4.22, 5.67, 5.89, 5.50, 5.12]})
pd.set_option('display.max_Columns', None)
for lag in range(1,7):
  df[f'price_lag{lag}M'] = df['price'].shift(lag)
print(df)

>>
    date  price  price_lag1M  price_lag2M  price_lag3M  price_lag4M  \
0      1   4.95          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1      2   5.04         4.95          NaN          NaN          NaN   
2      3   4.88         5.04         4.95          NaN          NaN   
3      4   4.22         4.88         5.04         4.95          NaN   
4      5   5.67         4.22         4.88         5.04         4.95   
5      6   5.89         5.67         4.22         4.88         5.04   
6      7   5.50         5.89         5.67         4.22         4.88   
7      8   5.12         5.50         5.89         5.67         4.22   

   price_lag5M  price_lag6M  
0          NaN          NaN  
1          NaN          NaN  
2          NaN          NaN  
3          NaN          NaN  
4          NaN          NaN  
5         4.95          NaN  
6         5.04         4.95  
7         4.88         5.04
```

I would like to calculate the slope of the lags for each month. I have mostly been using np.polyfit, and while it is quite fast, it gives me NaN if there's at least one NaN in the row.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
vars_to_consider = [f'price_lag{i}M' for i in range(1,7)]
Y = df.loc[:, vars_to_consider].values.T
df.loc[:, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[0].round(4)
df = df.drop(vars_to_consider, axis=1)
print(df)

>>
    date  price  price_trend_6M
0      1   4.95             NaN
1      2   5.04             NaN
2      3   4.88             NaN
3      4   4.22             NaN
4      5   5.67             NaN
5      6   5.89             NaN
6      7   5.50         -0.1694
7      8   5.12         -0.1937
```

I'd like to calculate the slopes for any of the non-null values and ignore the null values, but for all the rows. For a small data such as this one, I'd do something like this:

```
vars_to_consider = [f'price_lag{i}M' for i in range(1,7)]
for i in range(len(df)):
  Y = df.loc[i, vars_to_consider].values
  idx = np.where(~np.isnan(Y))[0]
  if len(idx) < 2:
    df.loc[i, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.nan
  else:
    df.loc[i, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(np.arange(len(idx)), Y[idx], 1)[0].round(4)
df = df.drop(vars_to_consider, axis=1)
print(df)

>>
   month  price  price_trend_6M
0      1   4.95             NaN
1      2   5.04             NaN
2      3   4.88         -0.0900
3      4   4.22          0.0350
4      5   5.67          0.2350
5      6   5.89         -0.0620
6      7   5.50         -0.1694
7      8   5.12         -0.1937
```

However, the original dataframe is around 300k rows long, and there are around 80 variables like 'price' that I want to calculate trends for. So the second method is taking too long. Is there a faster way to achieve the second output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize that since your largest `shift` is 6 rows, `np.polyfit` will return `nan` only for the first six rows. You could continue using `np.polyfit` for the entire dataframe and then simply iterate over the first six rows to correct those. Since you know you'll only iterate over a fixed, small number of rows, this will be much faster than iterating over *all* rows like you show in your second snippet of code.

```
# Vectorized call for the entire DF

# Note that X needs to be an array for the mask in the loop below to work
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

vars_to_consider = [f'price_lag{i}M' for i in range(1,7)]
Y = df.loc[:, vars_to_consider].values.T
df.loc[:, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(X,Y,1)[0].round(4)

# Fix first six rows
for i, row in df.head(len(X)).iterrows():
    ydata = row.loc[vars_to_consider].values
    mask = ~np.isnan(ydata) # Don't need `np.where` if we use boolean indexing

    if mask.sum() >= 2: # If >= 2 points, make a polyfit
        df.loc[i, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(X[mask],ydata[mask],1)[0].round(4)

df = df.drop(vars_to_consider, axis=1)
```

Which gives your desired result:

```
   date  price  price_trend_6M
0     1   4.95             NaN
1     2   5.04             NaN
2     3   4.88         -0.0900
3     4   4.22          0.0350
4     5   5.67          0.2350
5     6   5.89         -0.0620
6     7   5.50         -0.1694
7     8   5.12         -0.1937
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I do have multiple IDs with multiple dates, so it won't be the top 6 columns in my original dataset. But I can certainly select the rows that need mending, and the number of such rows will be much fewer than total.

Answer (score 0):

@Pranav's answer is great in order to solve the question as I framed it. My original data has multiple IDs that have multiple dates and prices, so it won't always be the top 6 rows. However, the rows for which the slope can be manually calculated with non-null values is much lesser than total rows. This is what I ended up using:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
vars_to_consider = [f'price_lag{i}M' for i in range(1,7)]
Y = df.loc[:, vars_to_consider].values
df.loc[:, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(X,Y.T,1)[0].round(4)

# Select indices where Y is not null
idx = ~np.isnan(Y)
# Count which rows have 2 to 5 nulls, since these rows need mending
idx2 = (idx.sum(axis=1) >= 2) & (idx.sum(axis=1) <= 5)
# Run a for loop with these rows, and calculate slopes with non-null values
for i in np.where(idx2)[0]:
  y = Y[i][~np.isnan(Y[i])]
  x = np.arange(len(y))
  df.loc[i, 'price_trend_6M'] = np.polyfit(x,y,1)[0].round(4)
df = df.drop(vars_to_consider, axis=1)
print(df)

>>
   month  price  price_trend_6M
0      1   4.95             NaN
1      2   5.04             NaN
2      3   4.88         -0.0900
3      4   4.22          0.0350
4      5   5.67          0.2350
5      6   5.89         -0.0620
6      7   5.50         -0.1694
7      8   5.12         -0.1937
```